# Style geometry in shapefile with NTS

Tags: nettopologysuite

I am using NTS to generate a shapefile based on users' selection of data in a web interface. Each item selected is represented by a linestring and all relevant dbf data is exported nicely and the user ends up with a single shapefile that contains all of the lines selected.

I would like to be able to color code each line based on the data associated with each line but do not see anything in the NTS library that would allow me to do that. Is it possible to do this and if so, how? The solution has to support pretty much any GIS tool.

Answer (score 2):

NTS has nothing to do with styling, like JTS definition says "is an API for modelling and manipulating 2-dimensional linear geometry".

On the other hand, there is no solution that supports any GIS tool. Each GIS software has his own styling format ArcMap (LYR), GeoServer (SLD), QGIS (QML and barely SLD), etc. QML and SLD are open formats, you can see his specifications to generate those files using your own code (don't know if there is any styling library), but for ArcMap you'll need a license to use ArcObjects.